# ResteasyHandlerMapping Resource Not Found for Swagger base url

Tags: java, xml, spring, swagger, resteasy

I was trying to integrate swagger with my project for api documentation. 
But restEasy is unable to map to my swagger base url inspite of config being provided.

I am not sure if i am missing some part of it or not. I have been doing research regarding this from few days now and mostly i am following their documentation [Swagger Integration documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-RESTEasy-2.X-Project-Setup#using-springs-bean-declaration).

My web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My spring-servlet.xml

```
<annotation-driven />
<beans:import resource="classpath:springmvc-resteasy.xml" />

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.sample.web.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.*.web">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider" />
</context:component-scan>
```

My applicationContext.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sample" />

<bean class="com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResourceJSON" />
<bean class="com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiDeclarationProvider" />
<bean class="com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ResourceListingProvider" />

<bean id="beanConfig" class="com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig">
    <property name="title" value="Swagger Sample App"/>
    <property name="version" value="1.0.0" />
    <property name="basePath" value="http://localhost:8100/rest"/>
    <property name="resourcePackage" value="com.sample.web.controller"/>
    <property name="scan" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

On running this project and then checking this url "localhost:8100/rest/api-docs/" i receive following stack trace

```
ERROR ResteasyHandlerMapping Resource Not Found: Could not find resource for relative : /rest/api-docs of full path: http://localhost:8100/rest/api-docs/ org.jboss.resteasy.spi.NotFoundException: Could no
```

t find resource for relative : /rest/api-docs of full path: localhost:8100/rest/api-docs/
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchChildren(RootSegment.java:360)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchRoot(RootSegment.java:374)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchRoot(RootSegment.java:367)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:297)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:173)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyHandlerMapping.getInvoker(ResteasyHandlerMapping.java:99)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyHandlerMapping.getHandler(ResteasyHandlerMapping.java:76)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:916)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:673)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: [followed this link & made changes](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-RESTEasy-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5)   `<bean class="io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource"/>
<bean class="io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers"/>
<bean id="beanConfig" class="io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig">
<property name="title" value="SwaggerApp"/>
<property name="version" value="1.0.0" /> 
<property name="basePath" value="http:localhost:8100/rest"/> 
<property name="resourcePackage" value="com.sample"/> 
<property name="scan" value="true"/>
 </bean>`